# Как создать форму леденца на палочке, складывая блоки по кругу?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, sass

Как складывать div по кругу, при этом последний div должен располагаться ниже первого div, но выше второго последнего div. Возможно ли это с помощью CSS?
Любая помощь будет оценена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Найдите [Codepen](https://codepen.io/vivekraj_kr/pen/VRyKNR). Предоставление образца фрагмента кода

```
<div class="frame">
  <div class="lolly-pop__wrapper">
    <div class="lollypop-top">
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.frame {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F5CE51;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.lollypop-top {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    .lollypop-top__item {
        position: absolute;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        top: -50%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        transform-origin: bottom;
        background-color: #fff;

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #D70606;
        }

        &:nth-child(1) {
            transform: rotate(30deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
            transform: rotate(60deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(4) {
            transform: rotate(120deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(5) {
            transform: rotate(150deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(6) {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(7) {
            transform: rotate(210deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(8) {
            transform: rotate(240deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(9) {
            transform: rotate(270deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(10) {
            transform: rotate(300deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(11) {
            transform: rotate(330deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(12) {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F5CE51;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.lollypop-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: -50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #D70606;
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="lolly-pop__wrapper">
    <div class="lollypop-top">
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to create a lollipop shape by stacking divs in a circular manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55158815/7394871) от участника  [@Vivekraj K R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4344359/vivekraj-k-r).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55158815/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Я бы создал это с учетом двух элементов (псевдоэлементов) и множественного радиального градиента. Вам нужно всего лишь дважды создать половину формы и повернуть одну из них.

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  background:
    /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5x75px   = 37.5px 
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866x75px = 64.95px       
       10.05px = 75px - 64.95px;
       112.5px = 75px + 37.5px
       139.95px = 75px + 64.95px
       37.5px = 75px - 37.5px
       */
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 139.95px 37.5px,red   98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 112.5px 10.05px,white 98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 75px    0,      red   98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 37.5px  10.05px,white 98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 10.05px 37.5px ,red   98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 0       75px,   white 98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 10.05px 112.5px,red   98%,transparent 100%);
}

.box::after {
 transform:rotate(180deg);
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы сделать вещи более забавными, мы можем добавить переменные CSS, чтобы легко управлять формой:

```css
.box {
  --R:50px; /*Radius*/
  --c1:red; /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  --g1:var(--c1) 98%, transparent 100%;
  --g2:var(--c2) 98%, transparent 100%;
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at var(--R)                        0                              ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at 0                               var(--R)                        ,var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1));
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
 transform:rotate(180deg);
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:80px;--c1:blue"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:100px;--c1:green;--c2:yellow"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:150px;--c1:white;--c2:pink"></div>
```

Обратите внимание, что Safari не поддерживает синтаксис с `at` (объясняется здесь [Как заставить радиальные градиенты работать в Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299171/8620333)), Поэтому вот другой синтаксис:

```css
.box {
  --R:50px; /*Radius*/
  --c1:red; /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  --g1:var(--c1) 98%, transparent 100%;
  --g2:var(--c2) 98%, transparent 100%;
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g1)) calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R) - var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R) - var(--R)),
     
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g1)) calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R) - var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R) - var(--R)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g2)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R) - var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R) - var(--R)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g1)) 0 calc(-1*var(--R)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g2)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R) - var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R) - var(--R)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g1)) calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R) - var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R) - var(--R)),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g2)) calc(-1*var(--R))  0,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,var(--g1)) calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R) - var(--R)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R) - var(--R));
   background-size:calc(2*var(--R)) calc(2*var(--R));
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
 transform:rotate(180deg);
 transform-origin:right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:80px;--c1:blue"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:100px;--c1:green;--c2:yellow"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:150px;--c1:white;--c2:pink"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159993/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Моим подходом был бы многоразовый SVG `<symbol>` с контурами, образованными кривыми квадратичного безье:

```css
#svg-lollipop path { transform-origin: 50% 50%; }

#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(2) {  transform: rotateZ(60deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(3) {  transform: rotateZ(120deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(4) {  transform: rotateZ(180deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(5) {  transform: rotateZ(240deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(6) {  transform: rotateZ(300deg); }

.lollipop {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.lollipop::before {
  content: "";
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.lollipop svg {
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.lollipop--animated {
  animation: rotate 10s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotateZ(0) }
  100% { transform: rotateZ(1turn) }
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
   <symbol id="svg-lollipop">
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
   </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="lollipop lollipop--animated" 
  style="background-color: #FFF; color:#E92120;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300"><use xlink:href="#svg-lollipop"></use></svg>
</div>

<div class="lollipop" 
  style="background-color: #004991; color:#007BC1;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300"><use xlink:href="#svg-lollipop"></use></svg>
</div>
```

**Как это работает:**

Та же форма была клонирована 6 раз и повернута, чтобы заполнить весь svg.
В этом примере каждая цветная фигура имеет угол `α = 30 градусов`.

Затем из тригонометрии мы можем найти координаты исходных точек для кривых: в пути координата `y 63.6` получается как `150 - (150 * tan (α))`, поэтому, если вам нужно изменить количество фигур и угол, вы можете легко найти исходные точки ([квадратичные кривые](https://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-paths-curve-commands/) действительно легко нарисовать).

Наконец, внешняя оболочка имеет `border-radius` и `hidden overflow`, чтобы придать округлую форму.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечный результат также является отзывчивым, поскольку внешняя оболочка сохраняет соотношение сторон 1: 1.

Белая область может быть изменена с помощью `background-color`, установленного на контейнере, цветная область может быть изменена вместо этого с помощью свойства `color` (для вашего удобства свойство fill элементов svg установлено на `currentColor`).

---

**кое-что я заметил позже:**

если добавить `box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #aaa;` для обертки изображение больше похоже на надувной воздушный шар на пляже, чем на леденец.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160086/7394871) от участника  [@Fabrizio Calderan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098851/fabrizio-calderan).</sub>